# UIAutomator 2 Run Shell Command on devices running API Level less than 21

Tags: android, eclipse, shell, android-uiautomator

I was using eclipse to write UIAutomator tests and doing the following tests on the command line to run them as described in several places on the web:

```
android create uitest-project -n myUITest -t 2 -p  C:\Users\JohnDoe\workspace\myUITest
ant build
adb push bin\myUITest.jar /data/local/tmp
adb shell uiautomator runtest myUITest.jar -c Tests.Test1
```

However, I recently migrated the test code to Android Studio to utilise the Android)Junit4, pick up uiautomator 2, and that everything is integrated into one place (adb monitor, build etc).
I followed the steps to add the following to my gradle file under app/source/Test. So far, so good.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    // Testing-only dependencies
    // Force usage of support annotations in the test app, since it is internally used by the runner module.
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    // UiAutomator Testing
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.testing.uiautomator.BasicSample"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

When running the tests, I am able to do gui tests like wakeup scree, swipe, touch BUT I see that I am no longer able to do shell events through the getRuntime.exec to mimic low level inputs (physical button presses) as before. Nothing happens when that code is run. 
Upon further researching, I saw that executeShellCommand (String command) is a new API added in level 21 that provides that capability. However, the device under test is running
kit kat (api level 19).

```
// Runtime.getRuntime used to work when working under eclipse before migrating to android studio/uiautomator 2
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sendevent /dev/input/eventX 1 678 1");  // some low level event
```

Is there a way to run shell commands or send low level/raw input events as it looks like sending shell commands through `Runtime.getRuntime` does not seem to work when working with UIAutomator2 and android studio and I do not believe I can use `UIAutomation executeShellCommand` as my device is running android kit kat (api 19).

I have spent over a day browsing posts but couldn't find a solution. Any help/guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. As you said, the API to execute commands as the shell user was added in API level 21. It is not possible to use this functionality on older platforms.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Are you aware of another way to generate user inputs using UiAutomator other than the shell setevent ? Also, I am currently using eclipse with UiAutojmator but would like to migrate to Android Studio using the version of uiautomator for API level 19. When I switch to android studio, I have no idea on how to set the uiAutomator to an older version.

Comment: Does UiDevice.pressKeyCode(...) work for your use case?

Comment: Good point Allen..The events I am generating are using this way:
       `shellCmd("sendevent /dev/input/event3 1 528 1")`
I even tried writing to the event3 files since all devices are represented as files. However, I got a permission error. 
I am not sure how  `shellCmd("sendevent /dev/input/event3 1 528 1")` translates to UiDevice.pressKeyCode(...).
Appreciate your time and valuable input.